# How to replace old drives in RAID 1 using WebBIOS?

Tags: sas, raid1, megaraid

Working with Sun Fire X4170 Server.

Now it have three RAIDs, all is on level 1. Every logical volume (every RAID) contains one Proxmox VM, idk does it matter in my case. The first RAID recognizes that there is no second drive, while the second RAID sees it as if one drive is degraded. And third RAID has two 128 GB drives.

The company has purchased new drives, and I need to replace all the old drives on the server without losing any configuration. Specifically, I need to replace the 128 GB drives with 300 GB drives in the third RAID (which is my main concern now). Based on my understanding, all the configuration needs to be done in WebBIOS.
So, thats how I see the solution algorithm for third RAID:

1. Make Offline one of old drives on Physical Drive Screen, then choose Prepare for Removal and extract drive from server phylically;
2. Add the new 300 GB drive;
3. On the Configuration Wizard screen choose Add Configuration, then create a new logical organization by selecting the remaining old drive and the new drive;
4. Wait for the array to rebuild;
5. Repeat all previous steps with a second new drive;
6. Make expanding of virtual drive from 128 to 300 GB on Virtual Drive screen.

Am I right in what I'm going to do for replacing drive? Or what should I do instead and how long will it take?

Sorry, I'm really new to the servers area and could be illiterate at some points, i guess. But I couldn't find helpful information for my situation so now I'm here.

Also I'm really sorry if my English isn't good enough.